How to connect to a WebSocket in React Native android with isTrusted:true? WebSocket in React Native returns "isTrusted": false (expo go, android)
I'm developing an app in React Native and I want to implement a WebSocket, but the WebSocket events come with isTrusted set to false, and I need it to be true.
When I test the same function in the browser console, isTrusted is true. Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong?
I'm using expo and expo go on my android phone to test
snack: https://snack.expo.dev/@pedroaf0/websocket-in-react-native-returns-istrusted-false-expo-go-android?platform=android
Code:
    import { StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Text, View } from 'react-native';
    export default function app() {

    function connectWebSocket() {
        console.log('Conectando ao WebSocket...');

        const socket = new WebSocket('wss://echo.websocket.org');

        // Evento disparado quando a conexão é aberta
        socket.addEventListener('open', function (event) {
            console.log('Conexão aberta com sucesso.');

            // Envia uma mensagem para o servidor WebSocket
            socket.send('Olá, servidor WebSocket!');
        });

        // Evento disparado quando uma mensagem é recebida do servidor
        socket.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
            console.log('Mensagem recebida do servidor:', event.data);
            console.log(event);
        });

        // Evento disparado quando ocorre um erro na conexão WebSocket
        socket.addEventListener('error', function (event) {
            console.error('Erro na conexão WebSocket:', event);
        });

        // Evento disparado quando a conexão é fechada
        socket.addEventListener('close', function (event) {
            console.log('Conexão WebSocket fechada:', event);
        });
        }

        return (
      
            <View style={styles.conteiner}>

           
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={connectWebSocket}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>conectar</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            
            </View>
          
           
    );
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    button: {
        backgroundColor: '#007AFF',
        borderRadius: 8,
        padding: 10,
        marginTop: 10,

    },
    buttonText: {
        color: 'white',
        textAlign: 'center',

    },
    conteiner: {
      flex: 1,
      alignContent: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',

    },
});


Logs in RN:
 LOG Connecting to WebSocket...
 LOG Connection opened successfully.
 LOG Message received from server: Request served by 7811941c69e658
 LOG {"data": "Request served by 7811941c69e658", "isTrusted": false}
 LOG Message received from server: Hello, WebSocket server!
 LOG {"data": "Hello, WebSocket server!", "isTrusted": false}

The same function executed in the browser returns in the logs:
 connectWebSocket()
 Connecting to WebSocket...
 Connection opened successfully.
 Message received from server: Request served by 7811941c69e658
 MessageEvent {isTrusted: true, data: 'Request served by 7811941c69e658', origin: 'wss://echo.websocket.org', lastEventId: '', source: null, …}
 Message received from server: Hello WebSocket server!
 MessageEvent {isTrusted: true, data: 'Hello, WebSocket server!', origin: 'wss://echo.websocket.org', lastEventId: '', source: null, …}

What is the difference?
How to connect to a WebSocket in React Native android in a Trusted way (isTrusted)?
I tried variations of this code, but it didn't make a difference:
const options = {
  headers: {
    'Sec-WebSocket-Protocol': 'echo-protocol',
  },
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
};

const ws = new WebSocket('wss://echo.websocket.org', [], options);


